# String equality not producing expected output

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, mongoose, equality

I am trying to equate two variables for some other code but despite being the same string I keep getting false. Here is the code I wrote:

```
app.post('/deletegraph', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    let {graph_name} = req.body
    console.log(graph_name)
    const user = await User.findById(req.session.user_id)
    console.log(user.graphs)
    for (let graph of user.graphs) {
        console.log(graph[1])
        console.log(graph_name)
        console.log(graph[1] === graph_name)
    }
    res.redirect('/graphs')
})
```

And this is the output in the terminal:

```
xsquared  
[  
[ 'http://localhost:3000/', 'xsquared', '.png' ],  
[ 'http://localhost:3000/', '2 exponent x', '.png' ]  
]  
xsquared  
xsquared  
false  
2 exponent x  
xsquared  
false
```

As you can see my graph_name variable is equal to 'xsquared' and in the first iterance of user.graphs, graph[1] is equal to 'xsquared'. This should output true but I get false. Does anyone know what's wrong?

I used console.log so that I know what the variables are but even when I see that they are the same I get false. I've tried double equals and triple equals and they both give me false.

Comment: What happens if you do console.log(String(graph[1]) === String(graph_name))

Comment: I tried that but now both iterances are true when the second should be false.

Comment: Interesting. what happens when you run `console.log(encodeURIComponent(graph[1]), encodeURIComponent(graph_name))`

Comment: or `let buff = new Buffer(graph_name);`
`let base64data = buff.toString('base64');` and logging `base64data` (and the same with `graph[1]`). my guess is there's some kind of white-space or special char somewhere. hmm, although  this doesn't align with the `String()`s comparison being true

Comment: What is the type of `req.body`? (what is the result of printing `console.log(typeof req.body, typeof graph_name);`)

Comment: Using the buffer methods worked, thanks.